# Configure different remote desktop user per build configuration on cloud service azure

Tags: azure, remote-desktop, azure-cloud-services

How do I configure different user for for different CSCFG for the remote desktop if I have multiple CSCFG files per build configuration.
right now, when I change remote desktop user while creating package, it replaces all cscfg files.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the Azure Powershell modules includes the ability to control RDP on cloud services:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/cloud-services-role-enable-remote-desktop-powershell/